# How to transfer precise volumes of viscous substances from a container to a beaker?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Pipetting doesn't work with viscous materials because the suction/pressure is not strong enough and because relatively high volumes of the liquid remain at the external walls of the pipette tip when withdrawing from the liquid.

So how can I transfer precise volumes (hundreds of microliters +/- 10%) of viscous substances?

Comment: Working in mass and not volume is usually more accurate with a good balance. Is it possible to cool/freeze the liquid, break it up and mass out what you need? This worked with some of the oils I used as a grad student,  but might not with biologics where the temp change might damage them.

Comment: Alternatively maybe heat the liquid if viscosity falls with temperature increase

Comment: Good comments from Stevie D, as a follow on, warm it up and measure by mass. If you can only do a large quantity,  measure into a volumetric flask and dilute with a solvent to give a specific concentration. Then pipette this.